# UIToolbar Lunacy Between iOS Versions

Tags: ios, ipad, ios4, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

So... My question is a bit of an odd one.  I have a simple UIToolbar being added to the view hierarchy of a navigationController called at viewDidLoad time.  Sounds simple, right?  Well here's the problem: the toolbar itself is transparent, but the buttons aren't in any version less than iOS 5.

I've tried all night to rearrange and reorder the calling of setFrame, setTranslucent, and setStyle, but nothing had worked, it's just blank!

So I had a brain fart: what if I made a new project, then made the exact same UIToolbar?  Well, it worked. Perfectly.  So I had another brain fart: what if it's just that my instance is broken?  So I made a new toolbar in the existing project, and it showed up blank...

This leads me to believe that my navigationController's view hierarchy is corrupted, but in what way, I have no idea...  Does anyone know how to solve my conundrum (Is this a simulator thing, or an iOS 4.3.2 thing?)?

CODE (works on iOS 5+, (hilariously despite deprecation), and in other projects, just not mine):

```
toolbar = [[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 22, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)]autorelease]; 
    [toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
    toolbar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin; 
    [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

Here are pictures from the iOS 4.3.2 simulator (top) and the iOS 5.0.1 simulator (bottom):
[image: iOS 4.3.2 Simulator] 
[image: iOS 5.0.1 Simulator]

EDIT: As per Rob's suggestion, I have changed the code to self.view addSubview... yet there is no change.  And as for his question as to why I do not utilize the navigationController's built in toolbar, it is because I actually have TWO toolbars that are animated up and down by that action button in the image.

EDIT 2: For clarity, observe the screenshots.  WHY is it INVISIBLE!!!?? I have the animations and view hierarchy down.  If anybody needs to see the viewDidLoad method, it's fairly massive and cumbersome...

Comment: Be more precise about what you are trying to do. Why do you need this toolbar _there_? Your code has no hints about custom needs... Usually one uses UINavigationController's `toolbarHidden` property as each navigation controller has a toolbar which is hidden by default. If you want to have a slider control in a toolbar, then pass it to the UIBarButtonItem's `initWithCustomView` method.

Comment: More precise?  How?  I have illustrated my problem as it stands, provided code, and shown screenshots.  What could possibly be more succinct?

Comment: I am getting exact problem. Did you got solution?

Answer (score 2):

You should not mess with the `UINavigationController`'s view tree.  You should only mess with the part of the view tree that you provide.

If you're using a `UINavigationController`, why don't you just use the toolbar that the navigation controller provides for you?

[*UINavigationController Class Reference*: Displaying a Toolbar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW30)
[*UINavigationController Class Reference*: Configuring Custom Toolbars](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW21)
[*UIViewController Class Reference*: `setToolbarItems:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/setToolbarItems%3aanimated%3a)

Comment: changed to self.view addSubview, no change.  Also, check the edit.

Comment: That's not what Rob said. You shouldn't mess with UINavigationController.view , as its behaviour is internal and subject to change between iOS versions. Instead, add the toolbar to the view of the view controller which you have previously pushed into the navigation controller.

Comment: I believe that is what I just did with the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's depreciated, why don't you try this [like it says in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent)?

```
[toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
[toolbar setTranslucent:YES];
```

Comment: Did that, didn't update the code.  Sorry.  But anyways, it's still Invisible.  It makes no sense.

Comment: @CodaFi: Then you're doing something wrong somewhere else in your code that you haven't shown.  Without more detail (and more code) we can't help.

Comment: But what?  It's pretty standard stuff.  The viewDidLoad method is MASSIVE, but simple.  Everything in it is just alloc, init, and addSubview.  I see no reason why this is happening; but it has devastating effects on user experience.

Answer (score -1):

You want the appearance of two toolbars sliding up and down according to the action button.  You don't really need two toolbars, though... try this as a transition:

```
[ toolbar setToolbarHidden: YES animated: YES ] ;
toolbar.topViewController.toolbarItems = < whatever the new toolbar should look like > ;
[ toolbar setToolbarHidden: NO animated: YES ];
```

The idea here is that the appearance of the toolbar would be controlled by the toolbarItems property of the current view controller, per the documentation.  You can make custom tool bar item instances that look pretty much like anything you want.

You might need to separate the two calls to setToolbarHidden: so that the run loop has a chance to draw the hidden toolbar before you bring it back.

Comment: No, I already have that.  My question is about why it would be invisible!

Comment: It is invisible because the UINavigationController is free to do whatever it wants with its view hierarchy, including putting something opaque in front of the toolbar you stuck in there.  Hence you really need to go with the flow instead of trying to impose your will on it. That's why I suggest using the toolbar provided by the navigation controller, which the navigation controller code knows about, and thus won't obscure.

Comment: But I'm not adding it to the navigation view hierarchy anymore and it didn't change